# SQLiteStudio: Is there a way to match row values from one table to column headers in another?

Tags: sql, join, datatable, sqlitestudio

Say I have Table1 that lists products and the quantities of the products being purchased, but the table does not have the price of the products for the specified quantities:

| ProductID | ProductName | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1234 | Shirt | 25 |  |
| B2345 | Pants | 100 |  |
| C3456 | Shoes | 200 |  |

Then I have Table 2 that has a quantity column and other columns who's names match the row values of the ProductID column from Table1.  The prices of these products are based on the quantity being purchased.

| Quantity | A1234 | B2345 | C3456 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | $500 | $200 | $150 |
| 50 | $800 | $400 | $200 |
| 100 | $900 | $300 | $230 |
| 150 | $950 | $350 | $210 |

Is there anyway I can use both the Quantity column and the ProductID column in Table1 to pull prices from Table2 into Table1?

I would prefer a solution that does not use the Pivot function as I am not yet working in SQLServer and I do not think I can use Pivot in SQLiteStudio.

Comment: Why did you tag MySql?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using `left join`

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.A1234, t3.B2345, t4.C3456) As Price from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.Quantity = t1.Quantity and t1.ProductID = 'A1234'
left join table2 t3 on t3.Quantity = t1.Quantity and t1.ProductID = 'B2345'
left join table2 t4 on t4.Quantity = t1.Quantity and t1.ProductID = 'C3456'
```

try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=cdcFSkPF9g)

Comment: This works great to pull the information I need, but I am having trouble turning it into an update statement that changes the values for the price column of Table1 in the appropriate rows.  It may also be worth noting that there are other rows in the Table 1 that I do not want to change (those unshown rows would not have any values in the quantity column).